# JavaFx comboBox items showing

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, javafx

I am developing app with JavaFx on my Linux PC. It's all right:
[image]

But, I tested this app on three different Windows PC (7, 7, 10) and got the same bug:
[image]

There are installed the same latest Java runtime on all of this PC's.

Part of my fxml code:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="comboBoxSpeed" layoutX="128.0" layoutY="69.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="111.0"/>
```

And controller:

```
comboBoxSpeed.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(Arrays.asList(Robot.availableSpeed)));
        comboBoxSpeed.getSelectionModel().select(0);
...
...
public final static Integer[] availableSpeed = {9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200};
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you get some sort of error that is present when running this on Windows?  This could possibly be a bug, but hard to tell without any additional error information like a stack trace.

Comment: I haven't got any errors.

Comment: I would report this to JavaFX Jira and see this as possibly a bug if there are no errors at all.